# Colocar h2 e button sobre imagem CSS

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web e gostaria de colocar o titulo `<h2>` e um button sobre uma imagem mas ao colocar o titulo e o button a imagem desalinha indo para baixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Link da minha aplicação](https://jsfiddle.net/v718rxtg/36/)

Comment: quero que a imagem  fique dentro dessas bordas pretas ,e o titulo e o botão sobre a imagem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crie uma classe e coloque o texto e o botão dentro dela, para separa-los da imagem:

```
<span class="bot_comprar">
   <h2>Bolos até R$30,00</h2>
   <button type="button" class="comprar_botao">Comprar</button>
</span>
```

No CSS, acrescente:

```
*{
   position: relative;
}

.bot_comprar{
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   z-index: 9;
}
```